# How to obtain difference in minutes between two raw dates in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, date, time

How to obtain difference in minutes between two raw dates in javascript? i.e. to use as '2 minutes ago', '10 minutes ago', etc.

By RAW I mean this format -> 2015-02-05T03:11:33.301Z (var x = new Date())

This is what I have but I always get NaN in the return value...

```
function getMinutesBetweenDates(startDate, index) {
    var endDate = new Date();
    var diff = endDate - startDate;
    return (diff / 60000);
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: how are you calling this function??

Comment: getMinutesBetweenDates(aux[i]['date'], i); imagine aux[i]['date'] is another new Date() obtained minutes before

Comment: Provided *startDate* is a Date, then the function will return a value in decimal minutes. So truncate the return value to remove the decimal part and add `' minutes ago'`.

Comment: If you are getting NaN, then startDate isn't a Date object. Is `(startDate instanceof Date)`?

Comment: damn... I didn't thought of that... the startDate was parsed with JSON.parse before calling the function... so it's only the format of the date not the instanceof Date :(

Answer (score 0):

I think problem would be the way you will be calling your function.

You should call it like bellow

```
var startDate = new Date("2015-02-05T03:11:33.301Z");
getMinutesBetweenDates(startDate);
```

It will print something like bellow

```
11.711916666666667
```

Just use `Math.floor` before returning value to get the result as `11`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

You have to convert `startDate` to a `Date` object even it's in the JSON format of `Date` object. The reason is, when you subtract, the `valueOf` method of the `Date` objects are called and subtracted. The return values of `valueOf` method are different in `Date` objects and `JSON` strings.

```js
function getMinutesBetweenDates(startDate) {
    var endDate = new Date();
    var startDate = new Date(startDate);
    document.write(startDate.valueOf());
    var diff = endDate - startDate;
    return (diff / 60000);
}

document.write(getMinutesBetweenDates("2015-02-05T03:11:33.301Z"));
```

Comment: That will happily return NaN in IE 8 and lower. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers will correctly parse a string in the OP format (a version of ISO 8601) however older browsers like IE 8 and lower will not. It's much safer to manually parse the string:

```
function parseISOutc(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(b[0], b[1] - 1, b[2], b[3], b[4], b[5], (b[6] || 0)));
}
```

Now your function can be:

```
function getMinutesBetweenDates(startDate) {
    return ((new Date() - parseISOutc(startDate)) / 6e4 | 0) + ' minutes ago';
}
```

The *index* parameter was unused so I removed it.